# Is it possible to use Access as a frontend to SQL Server and log all operations?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Is it possible to use Access as a front-end table editing interface, while logging an audit trail of changes at the back end on SQL Server? For example, if a user changes the value of one field on one row, could I intercept that UPDATE operation and write a record to an audit table logging who made the change and when?

Comment: Yes. Use a T-SQL trigger. Do some research on triggers, have a try and post back any specific issues. A trigger can be used to log changes to a table regardless of the front end

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible, read about triggers here; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Small SQL Example on how to enable Update and Insert triggers on a table;

```
CREATE TRIGGER employee_insupd
ON employee
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
```